# push repository on "server"

Tags: git

I'm trying to create a second repository for my project. So i've installed **gitolite** on my debian and i've configured it:

*conf/gitolite.conf*

```
repo    gitolite-admin
        RW+     =   git
        RW+     =   bux

repo    testing
        RW+     =   @all

repo    myprojectname
        RW+     =   bux
```

It's okay for gitolite-admin repo i can pull and push.
But i've problems with my **myprojectname**. I am in my existing project and i've configured "origin":

*.git/config*

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@myserver.domain.tdl:/home/git/repositories/myprojectname.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

So, when i try a push:

> $ git push origin master
>
> fatal: '/home/git/repositories/myprojectname.git'
>   does not appear to be a git repository fatal: The remote end hung up
>   unexpectedly

---

If i check on my server, the 'folder' doesn't exist:

```
ls -l /home/git/repositories/
total 8
drwx------ 8 git git 4096  4 janv. 14:20 gitolite-admin.git
drwx------ 7 git git 4096  4 janv. 14:20 testing.git
```

I've missed something ?

Comment: I've copied folder testing.git to myprojectname.git and it's working.
I think it's not the better way ... ^^

Answer (score 0):

Some helpful answers in this SO question:  [gitolite installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260648/gitolite-installation-issue)

Note in particular the 3rd answer down which reveals how you can get this error if you did not follow the installation instructions to the letter.  In particular, if the SSH key is giving a shell, this issue will happen.

I would closely follow the [SSH troubleshooting](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/ssh-troubleshooting.mkd) document, which should help you determine if this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Test your connectivity first. 'ssh -v gituser@server' will show you what key is being presented. Also ensure you have committed your public key to the admin project.

Comment: no problem with ssh & key. In my comment (on top message) i found a not clean "way"

Comment: Yes. gitolite should be creating these for you once you push up the config changes.

Comment: strange, so gitolite has not create it. Maybe file permission (but they look correct)

Comment: Might be that. I had similar issues initially. I forget exactly what I did.